# Geo location is not working in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am try to get the current geo location of the phone using 'plugin.geolocator' but it works fine in ios in android getting task cancellation exception. Here is the code I have tried. Please suggest any idea why I am getting this exception.

sample code:

```
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = -1;

            if (locator.IsGeolocationEnabled)
            {
                var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));
            }
```

These are the permissions I have gave in android manifest file.

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I am getting task cancellation exception while I am testing in emulator. I have tried with changing time span but no luck getting task cancellation exception only.

Comment: Do you have GPS enabled in your emulator?

Comment: yes, I have enabled gps in my emulator.  I have tested in physical device also, in physical device also gps is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Set a different value for Desired accuracy (big values -> more chance to have a result):

```
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 100;
```

Comment: I have tried with setting big value but not luck. Geo location is not working.

Comment: Downvote will not encourage people to help you... You post code with DesiredAccuracy=-1 that's the reason of my suggestion. You should use the complete snippet to handle all cases : https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/CurrentLocation.html I use this plugin and Geolocation works fine on a lot devices...

Comment: I haven't down voted the answer. If it is only possibility occure with my hands only. Can you please say that how can remove down voted, With my intentionaly I am not downvoted.

Comment: I have tried with that given link but  I am not get any position.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you also have to override OnRequestPermissionResult on your MainActivity class:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
{
   PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

}
```

And ensure your Android Target version is API 25+. See https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/GettingStarted.html

Comment: Hi, I have downloaded the Api 26 from android sdk manager but in target android version doesn't show the Api 26 level, it will show only up Api 25. How can I added that Api 26 in my target android version.